# How Borg backup handle data deduplication and ecryption?

Tags: backup, encryption, deduplication

I need a backup software which performs encryption clientside.

On [Borg Documentation](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#encrypted-repos) it is stated that it performs the encryption clientside and eventually if the repository is remote, another encryption layer is added if a secure connection is used (ex: ssh).

Borg uses data deduplication, so I red the [wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Data_deduplication) about this technology and I got myself aware of what it is and how it is performed.

Now I ask myself a question:

How can data deduplication work with encryption ?

The wikipedia page states it cannot, so I asked myself if Borg implemented some sort of witchcraft to handle this. Does it retreive the last backup, decrypt it and perform the hash comparisons ?

Is there any known method to handle this two methods (deduplication and encryption) together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borg stores a local cache of checksums of (chunks of) backed up data. This could be consulted before encryption, which makes the deduplication decision a *client-side* feature, that is not affected by encryption or compression.

From [the FAQ](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#can-i-backup-from-multiple-servers-into-a-single-repository):
**Can I backup from multiple servers into a single repository?**

*Yes, but in order for the deduplication used by Borg to work, it needs to keep a local cache containing checksums of all file chunks already stored in the repository. This cache is stored in ~/.cache/borg/. If Borg detects that a repository has been modified since the local cache was updated it will need to rebuild the cache. This rebuild can be quite time consuming.*

Comment: Can you please tell your sources ?

Comment: http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#when-backing-up-to-remote-encrypted-repos-is-encryption-done-locally http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#when-backing-up-to-remote-servers-do-i-have-to-trust-the-remote-server http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals.html